# Python - How to get the name of a list when used in a nested for loop

Tags: python, arrays, variables, if-statement

I am using `python 2.6.6`

I'm trying to use an `if` statement that checks for the name of a list in a nested for loop.

This is my code:

```
blueList = ["light blue", "dark blue"]
redList = ["light red", "dark red"]
orangeList = ["light orange", "dark orange"]

colorsGroup = [blueList, redList, orangeList]

for member in colorsGroup:
    for colorNameInList in member:
        if "orange" in member.__name__:
            print("the name of this list contains the word orange")
        elif "red" in member.__name__:
            print("the name of this list contains the word red")
        elif "orange" in member.__name__:
            print("the name of this list contains the word orange")
```

I keep getting:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

What can I use that would allow me to check against the name of a list if that attribute doesn't exist?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Objects don't keep references to the names that are bound to them. You'll need to use a `dict` if you want that functionality.

Comment: Why iterate over the list to begin with if you're just going to do something different based on which list you're iterating over? This is a [Loop-switch antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence).

Comment: Why not use a `dict` like `{'blue': blueList, 'red': redList}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your variable names to be read, consider using them, for exemple, as keys of a dictionnary:

```
colorsGroup = {'blueList':blueList, 'redList':redList, 'orangeList':orangeList}
```

You can then iterate like this:

```
for key, value in colorsGroup.iteritems():
    if 'blue' in key:
        print("the name of this list contains....")
    elif 'orange' in key:
        print("the name of this list contains...")
    else:
        print("the name of this list contains...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are trying to do is not possible. This is because lists work as reference in python. Consider the following code:

```
     a = [1,2,3,4]
     b = a
```

Here both a and b point to the same list. Therefore it is difficult to get the name of the variable based on the list.

With the said, there is a work around that can be done in your code. The following code should do the trick.

```
    import inspect
    def retrieve_name(var):
         callers_local_vars = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.items()
         return [var_name for var_name, var_val in callers_local_vars if var_val is var]
```

But i should also inform you that it may do the trick but something like this should not be done.